# One distributes $10$ cookies evenly between $0$ people. How much does each person get?

Tags: logic, fair-division

This "task" is supposed to show the problems with dividing by zero. However, how does one resolve this?

1. There is no correct answer, since there are no people you could make the statement about.
2. Every person gets $13.37\pi$ cookies, since any $\forall$-statement about an empty set is true.
3. There is no correct answer, because…

Comment: No correct answer. By definition, $\frac{10}{0}$, if defined should be a unique number. It can't be $13.37 \pi$ and $e^{-e^{-e^{12}}}$ at the same time.

Comment: I hope and wish that you noticed that $13.37\pi \approx 42$  which is the  *Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, The Universe, and Everything* . https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29

Comment: There is no correct answer, because no matter how many cookies you give to each person, you'll never end up distributing all $10$ cookies.

Comment: I'd go with 2., since there is no person who doesn't get $13.37\pi$ cookies.

Comment: An engineer thinks that his equations are an approximation to reality. A physicist thinks reality is an approximation to his equations. A mathematician doesn't care.

Comment: A mathematician and an engineer are sitting at a table drinking when a very beautiful woman walks in and sits down at the bar.

The mathematician sighs. "I'd like to talk to her, but first I have to cover half the distance between where we are and where she is, then half of the distance that remains, then half of that distance, and so on. The series is infinite. There'll always be some finite distance between us."

The engineer gets up and starts walking. "Ah, well, I figure I can get close enough for all practical purposes."

Answer (score 2):

When we are talking about dividing between 0 people, we're dealing with division by 0.

Logic says, given any empty set **S**,  ∀**x P(x)** is always true. In other words, the answer is true for all elements belonging to the universe of discourse. This contradicts with the uniqueness property of a binary operation over real numbers. Hence, the answer is undefined.

On an informal note, it doesn't make a lot of sense when someone wants to divide 10 bucks between nobody. You need a non-zero number to start with and hence, division by zero is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is not a good answer for this question, since it is a real live question. You can try to model it into a term or a formular that might be solved, but the answer depends on your model.

For example, you could just go for $\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \frac{10}{t}$ and get the answer $\infty$, but you also could ask for the multiplicative inverse of $0$ in the $\mathbb{R}$ (to put it into $10 \cdot 0^{-1}$) and get "There is no solution for that.".

Answer (score 0):

Everyone here immediately starts talking about dividing by zero, but we should first note that the question is not about dividing by zero, but about distributing cookies evenly among zero people.

The most important thing that we have to clarify here is the definition of "divide evenly".

**Case 1:** "Divide evenly" means that every person gets the same amount of cookies.

In that case, we could just give each one of the zero people exactly $17$ cookies and we're done. No two people have different amounts of cookies.

A correct answer, therefore, is "$17$ cookies".

However, this definition of "divide evenly" implies that cookies may be left over. According to it, we could divide $10$ cookies evenly over two people by giving each person $3$ cookies and leaving $4$ cookies over. This definition may not be the one we intended.

**Case 2:** "Divide evenly" means that every person gets the same amount of cookies, and there are no cookies left over.

In that case, we clearly can't divide $10$ cookies over $0$ people, since there are always $10$ cookies left over.

Now the premise of the question, "One distributes cookies evenly between $10$ people", is a contradiction.

A contradiction implies anything, especially that "$17$ cookies" is a correct answer.

**Conclusion:** "$17$ cookies" is a correct answer, no matter how we define "divide evenly".